# How can I have one network card that allows traffic between two private networks?

Tags: networking, cisco

This is a a question about a private network.

I have two servers (Linux), srv1, srv2, each has one NIC.
I have two switches (Cisco 3750), sw1, sw2

The servers are on two different subnets.

srv1 is on 192.168.1.0 (network A, sw1) .> the A and B are not classes, only represent the networks for the question

srv2 is on 192.16.2.0 (network B, sw2)

If A wants sends out traffic for B via sw1 (the one A is physically connected to) and ip routing is turned on on the switches, sw1 & sw2, do I need a specific gateway for the sw2 traffic?

Let me ask another way,

- If svr1 send traffic to svr2 and I only have one physical network
  connection to to sw1, what happens to the packet?
- Will packet ever make it to the Cisco switch from the box?
- Or does it get to the switch and die?
- Get routed?
- Isn't a unique gateway only need when you have more than one physical
  NIC?

I simplified the question, but in reality the sw2 subnet is on a private network along with many devices, specifically a SAN I want sw1 to be able to get to (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

You have to have routing set up correctly.

For example:
SRV1 IP: 192.168.1.10/24 
SRV2 IP: 192.168.2.10/24

SW-A IP: 192.168.1.1/24
SW-B IP: 192.168.2.1/24
(these you can set up as interface VLAN and switches should be interconnected)

In order for SRV1 to access SRV2, you should set the routing on SRV1 to:

192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.1

And on SRV2 (for reverse packet)

192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.1

Hope it helps

Comment: So on the first server (.1), if I try to ping .2, I can't see it, but if I put a route in .1 to use switch1 for the .2 traffic, it will work, assuming if have IP Routing turned on in the switches?

Comment: yes, and switches should be connected to each other to pass this traffic